# useFetch hook with typescript and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a question about the implementation useFetch hook with typescript and Axios.

Here is I find some example useFetch hook. But It's a javascript implementation. I just gave there any to response and err.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-hook-gtiec?from-embed=&file=/src/components/App.js

so here is my useFetch hook .ts file.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useFetch = ({
    api,
    method,
    url,
    data = null,
    config = null,
}: any) => {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            api[method](url, JSON.parse(config), JSON.parse(data))
                .then((res : any) => {
                    setResponse(res.data)
                })
                .catch((err : any) => {
                    setError(err)
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    setIsLoading(false)
                })
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [api, method, url, data, config])

    return { response, error, isLoading }
}
```

and here is my component where I make fetch request via useFetch.

```
  const { response, isLoading, error } = useFetch({
        api: BaseURL,
        method: 'get',
        url: 'some',
    })
```

everything works well request is works.
But when I try to pass to my some child component (child component wait string value) some string value from response.

here is the child component in the component where I make a fetch request.

```
return (
    <Title>{response && response.id}</Title>
)
```

here is the title component

```
type Props = {
    children: string
}
export const Title: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
    return <h4>{children}</h4>
}
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | (string & {}) | (string & ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>) | (string & ReactNodeArray) | (string & ReactPortal)'.ts(2322)
Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
```

It's the first question of how I can implement this hook in a typescript way.

And here using fetch API. How I can use here Axios?

Comment: `children: string | null`

Comment: Do I need to add every type | null? I think it's not so correct, not?

Comment: `response && response.id` can be `null` (before request is completed), so you have 2 options: allow `children` to be `null` or provide some fallback (e.g. `response?.id ?? ''`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you currently have 2 problems need to resolve as following:

- In your custom hook, you use a state `const [response, setResponse] = useState(null)` which tells `response` always `null` which can end up an issue where you check here `{response && response.id}`. So I suggest you to fill the type for response in generic type:

```js
export const useFetch = <R extends any = any>({
  api,
  method,
  url,
  data = null,
  config = null,
}: any) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<R | null>(null); // set `R` as returned type
  // ...
}
```

Then you specify your response where you use your custom hook:

```js
const { response, isLoading, error } = useFetch<{ id: string }>({
  // ...
});
```

- Another thing is to refine is the `children` type is supposed to be `React.ReactNode`

```js
type Props = {
    children: React.ReactNode
}
```

Comment: @user3348410 Side note: when you use `FC` no need to type `children` explicitly